# Is there another way to put data in datagridview? i've got this error "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."

Tags: vb.net

I try to put data in datagridview in vb.net and when i run my program i got this error "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table."
can anyone correct my code? i was new in vb.net thank you.

by the way here's my code

```
Private Sub Cashier_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PosDgv()
End Sub

Public Sub PosDgv()
    Dim table As New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add("Number of Items", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Food Category", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Food Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Quantity", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Price", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dgvAddPos.DataSource = table
End Sub


Private Sub btnAddtoRev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddtoRev.Click
    table.Rows.Add(lbNum.Text, cbxFoodCat.Text, cbxFoodName.Text, txtQty.Text, lbTotal.Text, lbDate.Text, lbTime.Text)
    dgvAddPos.DataSource = table
End Sub
```

the error was thrown to `table.Rows.Add(lbNum.Text, cbxFoodCat.Text, cbxFoodName.Text, txtQty.Text, lbTotal.Text, lbDate.Text, lbTime.Text)`

Comment: Change it to `table = New DataTable` since you already declared it.

Comment: You need to read up on 'Scope'.  The table you created in `Sub PosDgv` exists only there.  Then, study up on Datatypes; `Price` probably ought not be integer and Date probably ought to be Date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this... You don't need to set the datasource more than once.

```
Dim table As New DataTable

Private Sub Cashier_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PosDgv()
End Sub

Public Sub PosDgv()
    table.Columns.Add("Number of Items", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Food Category", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Food Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Quantity", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Price", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Time", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    dgvAddPos.DataSource = table
End Sub

Private Sub btnAddtoRev_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddtoRev.Click
    table.Rows.Add(lbNum.Text, cbxFoodCat.Text, cbxFoodName.Text, txtQty.Text, lbTotal.Text, lbDate.Text, lbTime.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: No problem, and remember your scope :)